# JSP gets refreshed on using JSON as parameters on Onclick of button

Tags: java, json, jsp

I am using a jsp page and onClick of button I am doing this:

```
onClick="javascript:document.form1.<%=Constants.ACTION_FIELD%>.value='<%=Constants.EDIT_BUTTON%>'; document.form1.abc.value=<%=selectParam%>">
```

Here abc is a hidden variable and I am passing a json object in this like `{"Name":"Doe","seq",1};`

Whenever I try to load this page the page loads/gets refreshed times again.

If I do `selectParam = selectParam.replace("\"", "'");` then page doesn't get refreshed again but this doesn't solves my purpose as I don't get proper JSON values. What can be the workaround? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to do many things in one event. Try using javascript function and set the href target to "". Return false in javascript function to avoid refresh.

```
<a href="" onclick=" return populatevlues()">Click me</a>

function populatevlues()
{
  ...
  ...
  return false;
}
```